# Cold Fusion Where do place the code for cfschedule?

Tags: coldfusion, scheduled-tasks

I want to set up a simple scheduled task in ColdFusion.  I will not have access to the Administrator.  So I plan to use`<cfschedule`.  The web is teeming with examples of how to write a cfschedule tag.  But I cannot find any explanation of where to put the code.

Do I place it on any .cfm page?  Must it go in the index.cfm or Application.cfm?  Or what?

I also could not find any explanation of how the scheduling code is initiated.  Is it sufficient that the cfschedule code should be somewhere in the application?  And if not, what should I do to make sure it runs.

These questions feel stupid to me, but I just can't find answers.   Can anyone enlighten me?.cfm

Comment: cfschedule is just like any other CFML tag or function. Place it within a blank cfm file (or cfc) then execute that code by loading the cfm script within a browser. You only need to execute that script once, in order to create the scheduled task.  If the task is successfully created, then CF takes over, automatically calling the specified `url` on whatever schedule you specified (hourly, daily, etc...). If you want to know when the task  executes, add some code to the `url` cfm script to notify you via email, like Dan said.

Comment: As others have already explained, the `cfschedule` tag itself can be placed in any CF code file that you are able to execute on your site, and it only needs to be executed once, in order to create the scheduled task entry. However it's worth pointing out that if this is on an environment where you have no access to CF Administrator, then it sounds like it might also be the type of environment where the server admin will have denied permission to execute `cfschedule`.

Answer (score 2):

Off the top of my head I didn't know, so I googled `cfschedule example` and looked at [this page](https://cfdocs.org/cfschedule).

The first example was to create or update a task.  It says, tell ColdFusion to run 'importData.cfm' daily at 7AM

```
<cfschedule
 action="update"
 task="importMyCSVFileToDB"
 operation="HTTPRequest"
 startDate="5/12/2016"
 startTime="7:00 AM"
 url="http://www.example.com/scheduled/importData.cfm"
 interval="daily" />
```

My interpretation of that is that you put a `<cfschedule>` tag with a `action="update"` attribute on a page on the relevant server, and run it once.  If it was me, I'd make it page with only the `<cfschedule>` tag followed by the word, done.

To test this theory, write a page that sends you a simple email.  Then schedule that page as I just described and see if you get the email at the scheduled time.

Comment: Yes, I read that page and many others like it.  It does not anywhere say where to put the code, or how to invoke. it.  Same with all the other sites I had found.  Your powers of inference are obviously much better than mine.    I finally did locate a site which addresses  these trivial matters:  https://himansusekharkhuntia.blogspot.com/2014/10/perform-scheduled-tasks-using-coldfusion.html.